# Android - inputStream.read() - I can not read anything

Tags: java, android, sockets, stream, inputstream

I have a problem with read data from socket. I was trying solve my problem in different way and i think my code now is the simplest possible to test it. Android have a problem to read from socket and stop in this line( inStream.read() ). After 10s( socket.setSoTimeout ) i have a message -------error: null. I want to read any data( 0-255 ) or -1, but nothing has happend. In PHP( on my server, my code) and PC( not my app ) everything is fine. What should I do?

It is my first post, so i am sorry for possible mistakes. Thanks for your help!

```
try{
    socket      = new Socket( "192.168.0.150", 502 );
    socket.setSoTimeout( 10000 );

    outStream   = new DataOutputStream( socket.getOutputStream() );
    inStream    = new DataInputStream( socket.getInputStream() );

    System.out.println("----------" + outStream);
    System.out.println("----------" + inStream );

    outStream.write( 0x01 );
    outStream.write( 0x03 );
    outStream.write( 0x10 );
    outStream.write( 0x00 );
    outStream.write( 0x00 );
    outStream.write( 0x04 );
    outStream.write( 0x40 );
    outStream.write( 0xC9 );

    outStream.flush();
    System.out.println("----------ok 1");

/////////////////////////////               

//  Thread.sleep( 50 );
    System.out.println("----------Test1: " + socket.isConnected() );
    System.out.println("----------Test2: " + socket.isInputShutdown() );

    int dat = inStream.read();
    System.out.println("----------ok2: " );
} catch( Exception e ){
    e.printStackTrace(); // <-- edit
    System.out.println( "----------Error: " + e.getMessage() );
}


------------

    <uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS" />
    <uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

--edit--

My logs: http://codepaste.net/eapot2

Comment: Use e.printStackTrace() in order to get meaningful output related to caught exception.

Comment: I add this line. My logs: http://codepaste.net/eapot2

If I delete socket.setSoTimeout( 10000 ); then Android crashes( nothing happens )

Answer (score 0):

If you got a read timeout, obviously nothing is being sent by the peer.

NB 'nothing happens' is not the same thing as 'Android crashes'. Don't misuse standard terminology.

Comment: OK. So maybe I should discribe problem again. If I send "01 03 10 00 00 04 40 C9" in PHP( as chr( hexdec($value) for each number ) I have response. My code in Android do nothing in this line( waiting for response ). If I do not have timeout I can wait all the time, but i don't have response. Possible that in a bad way to send data, but how should I do? With other device this code was fine and I have response message, but now it is deavice form other company and I have a problem. Maybe I should use "sleep" in program for 50ms before use "read"? But Thread.sleep(50); do not help me.

Answer (score -1):

Change port to 1024-65565. Port 502 is usually not allowed.

Comment: But I want to comunicate via modbus - it is on 502 port( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers ). This port is a standard, so I have to read from that.

Thanks for answer and I wait for another advice.

Comment: Changing the port number won't solve a read timeout. Not an answer.

Comment: But if i change port on localhost, this work (using only write and read, not to modbus)